# LWJGL Renderer Thread Error

Tags: applet, game-engine, lwjgl, java-web-start, jmonkeyengine

Guys I have a trouble with jmonkeyengine. In jme3's forum I could not get any efficient help on my problem. Actually no one says what my problem is. Because I am new in lwjgl and jme3, I also do not know what happens. Simply I have created a basicGame on jmonkey which is first template as an example. Then I created its applet or webstart distros. When I run it, it throws an exception occuring between jme3 and lwjgl. And it says:

```
Exception in thread “LWJGL Renderer Thread” java.lang.IllegalStateException: No loader registered for type “fnt”
    at com.jme3.asset.ImplHandler.aquireLoader(ImplHandler.java:199)
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:266)
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadFont(DesktopAssetManager.java:365)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.loadGuiFont(SimpleApplication.java:178)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:186)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the code of BasicGame template in jme3:

```
/**
 * test
 *
 * @author normenhansen
 */
public class Main extends SimpleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main app = new Main();
        app.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        Box b = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, 1, 1, 1);
        Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);

        Material mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        mat.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Blue);
        geom.setMaterial(mat);

        rootNode.attachChild(geom);
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
        //TODO: add update code
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleRender(RenderManager rm) {
        //TODO: add render code
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

**- BasicGame project has been built on either Linux or Windows**

**- Original JMonkeyEngine SDK has been used**

**- An example is in http://appletgame.comeze.com/ (just click on 'run-applet.html')**

**- File Permissions on the webpage are 755 for all files.**

Is there someone who knows why I get this error and what could be done?

Comment: Could you edit in the code you used that generated this exception

Comment: And are you using Jmonkey within its own IDE or as an external library?

Comment: @RichardTingle I directly use jmonkey sdk on linux. And I do not know what causes that exception

Comment: Well if you post your code I'll have a look at it, but I use JMonkey through the IDE so if its an enviroment problem I may not be the man to help you

Comment: @RichardTingle I edited the question you can see the code. As you may know it is the test program created by norman, that is all.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry. I hope someone with linux experience turns up as clearly there’s no problem with your code

Comment: @RichardTingle you mean there is no problem with code and the sdk. If so what makes the difference in linux :S I can use the sdk full functionally, I can build and I can run in the sdk. :S anyways thank for your attention :)

Comment: @RichardTingle Nothing changes in Windows. I have edited the question you may find the details.

Comment: @ErayTuncer this message means there are mismatch between lwjgl library that you used and the JME3 is looking for ? may i know from where you copied the lwjgl and natives and put them into your project's classpath ?

Comment: @Mihir I have never done such things because Jmonkey holds all libraries in it. I just benefit from jmonkey's sdk to create its distro. It works when I create desktop distro of the game but not for applets.

Comment: it has been too long Mihir :) I really do not remember at all sorry :( When I leaved the project, it was actually working but I do not remember how :S